# Unable to receive FCM topic data messages in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

The goal here is to receive only *data messages* from Firebase FCM when the app subscribes to a particular topic.

I've gone thru the FCM tutorial, and I am able to receive notification messages.  So I know that my setup with Firebase is correct.  Its when I try to only receive data messages I have issues

Here is my code :
First the script for sending the data message to FCM as a topic data messages

```
curl -d '{ 
  "topic": "/topics/sonicfxinstructions",
  "data": {
    "one" : "1",
    "two" : "2"
  }
}' \
-i -H "Application/json" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-X POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

And my code for messages ..basically a cut and paste from the FCM documents

```
extension AppDelegate:  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                  willPresent notification: UNNotification) async
        -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // ...

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
            return [[.banner, .sound]]
      }

      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                  didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // ...

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
      }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) async
      -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)

      return UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData
    }
    
    
}

extension AppDelegate:  MessagingDelegate {
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

      let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dataDict
      )
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    
      Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "sonicfxinstructions") { error in
          if let error = error {
              print("Error subscribing to topic: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          } else {
              print("Subscribed to topic successfully")
          }
       }
    
        
    }
```

When I subscribe to a topic I get the "Subscribed to topic successfully" message back.  So I am out of ideas on where to look on why topic messages are not getting delivered when notifications messages are.

Comment: Everything works fine when you remove the `data` and add `notification` instead? Also what happens if you remove `/topics/` from "topic": "/topics/sonicfxinstructions" of the req?

Comment: According to the docs you have to have /topics there.  I tried with no result.
If I  set the message to a notification then it comes thru, so I know I have thing right.  I'm trying  do two things. 1.  Send a message as strictly data and 2. send it as a topic message.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
Shows that message format..  But in this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple  it looks like you are supposed to be able to do this.  I was able to send data with a notification element in it.  But I cant get topics to work.